# How to get information about connectors via JMX or EmbeddedActiveMQ

Tags: activemq-artemis

For `acceptors`, I can get data like `embeddedActiveMQ.getActiveMQServer().getAcceptors()` or with `AcceptorControl`

But for `connectors` I don't find any way to get data or create/delete `connector`, not in JMX or EmbeddedActiveMQ.

I added to a `broker.xml` a `connector`

```
<connectors>
  <connector name="connector1">tcp://192.168.58.6:61716</connector>
</connectors>
```

And I thought that I get info about this `connector` via

`embeddedActiveMQ.getActiveMQServer().getConnectorsService().getConnectors()`

But this returns size 0.

Artemis version 2.16.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using JMX for management then you can use the `getConnectorConfigurations()` method on the `ActiveMQServerControl`.

If you're using `EmbeddedActiveMQ` then you can use `embeddedActiveMQ.getActiveMQServer().getConfiguration().getConnectorConfigurations().values()`. That will give you a `Collection<TransportConfiguration>` of the connectors which you've configured.

The difference between acceptors and connectors in this context is that an acceptor is standalone resource which is deployed and managed independently of anything else. A connector, on the other hand, is essentially just a configuration container which is referenced and used by *other* components (e.g. a bridge). A connector is not deployed in and of itself.

Comment: Is it possible to somehow directly (not only TransportConfiguration): 1. Get the objects of the available running connectors `NettyConnector/InVMConnector` 2. Create or remove a connector without rebooting the broker? Or how did you write connectors just config containers and the objects (`NettyConnector/InVMConnector`) themselves are not created or run?

Comment: The "running connectors" are on the clients so you can't get them from the broker. You can add a connector configuration using `org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.config.Configuration#addConnectorConfiguration`. You can remove a connector configuration by using `org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.config.Configuration#getConnectorConfigurations` and modifying the returned map. I'm not sure this is exactly what you're after. If not, it might help to explain in detail what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I don’t understand “running connectors are on the clients”. In doc https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/ written – “A connector is used when the server acts as a client”. When I create a `bridge` from server 1 to server 2, on the server 1 I create a `connector` with an `acceptor` address and port on server 2 and it turns out that server 1 acts as a client. Then on which server can you get access to “running connectors“ (objects `NettyConnector/InVMConnector`)?

Comment: In the case of a bridge, the bridge is running on the broker and acting as a client and it is using the URL you configured in the referenced connector to make that connection. However, the running connector is still in the client (i.e. the bridge) and there's really nothing you can do with it directly. The `BridgeControl` exists for various management operations, but you still can't get access to the running connector. As I said before, maybe it would help to explain in detail exactly what you're trying to accomplish. It seems your fundamental understanding of the connector may be incorrect.

Comment: I don't understand why you want access to the actual running connector which the client is using. What do you want to do with it? It's under the client's control. There's really nothing you should do with it and there's no management API for it anyway.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to understand what a connector is and what useful things can be done with it in more detail. Thanks for the information.